# Knapsack 0-1 recursive subproblem graph

Tags: algorithm

How do you draw subproblem graph for 0/1 knapsack recursive solution?

Comment: you might want to look at this : http://www.cse.unl.edu/~goddard/Courses/CSCE310J/Lectures/Lecture8-DynamicProgramming.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked at the link you provided. I saw the table being populated for Knapsack example. Is the table the sub- problem graph ? I was hoping if there is something with vertices and edges just like you would get for Fibonacci algorithm. Your help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: @Josh: try to ask on Computer Science SE site http://cs.stackexchange.com/. You may get some answers there.

Answer (score 1):

[image]